# Question about the definition of the least upper bound property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Definition:** Let $A$ the set with order relation. We say that the set $A$ has least upper bound property if any $A_0\subset A$, $A_0\neq \varnothing$ which *has upper bound* has the least upper bound.

**Question 1:** When we say "has upper bound..."  do we mean that its upper bound is in $A$?

**Question 2:** When we say "has the least upper bound..."  do we mean that its least upper bound is in $A$?

> **Example:** Consider the set $A=(-1,1)$ of real numbers in the usual order. Assuming the fact that the real numbers have least upper bound
>   property, it follows that the set $A$ has the least upper bound
>   property (why?). For given any subset of $A$ having an upper bound in
>   $A$ , it follows that its least upper bound must be in $A$. For
>   example, the subset $\{-1/2n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $A$, thought it
>   has no largest element, does have a least upper bound in $A$, the
>   number $0$.
>
> $ \quad $ On the other hand, the set $B=(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ does not
>   have th least upper bound property . The subset $\{-1/2n: n\in
> > \mathbb{N}\}$ of $B$ is bounded above by any element of $(0,1)$, but
>   it has no least upper bound in $B$.

I have read this example very carefully and I guess that it provides an example of subsets of reals which has LUB-property and has not, respectively.

Do I correctly interpreted the meaning of above example?

Comment: Q1&2. Yes.${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Your point is that if a set $A$  has the least upper bound property, it does not imply that every subset of A also has the least upper bound property.

Yes, you are quite right.

A good example is the set of rational numbers which does not have the least upper bound property while it is a subset of real numbers which has the least upper bound property.